# Does the program I downloaded (bitcoin-qt) mine bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, solo-mining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I start mining Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin)

Nothing ever says how to actually mine bitcoins, except to join a pool. I don't want to do that. All I really know is that each block has an equation associated with it, and whoever solves it gets the coins. I assume that the miner is trying to solve the equation, and I also assume that this just means running the bitcoin client and hoping your computer can generate a block. If bitcoin qt (from the website) doesn't mine bitcoins, what does?

Comment: I think you've gotten the wrong impression. Bitcoin is not about mining. You don't need to mine, and I recommend you don't. If you do want to mine, you need dedicated hardware, dedicated software and a pool.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, but not efficiently. In fact, CPU's are so bad at mining bitcoin that the option was removed from the user interface. However, the code is still there (though mostly as a reference implementation), and you can go to Help > Debug Window > Console and type in "setgenerate true" to turn it on.  Type "setgenerate false" to stop.

You can also give bitcoin the option `-gen` at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The client cannot mine by itself you need a miner for that. However you will need the client to relay the blocks you find and to getwork if you mine alone. Try [guiminer](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=3878.0) for starter it can mine on his own or on a pool.

And you should really join a pool since it can be really difficult to mine by your own (exept if you have 1.5 Thash/s mining rig ready)