# What was the first official BTC miner software?

Tags: wallet, client, mining-software

I know that the first and official wallet is bitcoin-qt. This wallet has code here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

What was the first official miner software? I understand that bitcoin-qt never use as miner software. Where is official code of miner software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first official mining software was Bitcoin Core (then known simply as Bitcoin, later bitcoin-qt), and it [still serves](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/does-the-program-i-downloaded-bitcoin-qt-mine-bitcoins) as a reference mining implementation, making it the "official" miner. See its [miner.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/miner.cpp) file, for example.

Bitcoin Core uses your CPU to mine. Mining eventually moved to GPUs and ASICs, so that mining on a CPU is practically pointless right now. In that sense, you should never use Bitcoin Core as mining software. But it still is mining software.

Comment: The original client was called just "Bitcoin" and used wxWidgets rather than QT. Starting with version 0.5 it was merged with Bitcoin-qt, but by then mining had already been disabled.