# What bitcoin mining software is easy to use and start mining immediately with a pool & new ASIC boards?

Tags: asic, mining-software

I'm looking to just start mining with my cheap laptop, but wanted to just ask whats the easiest mining software to setup and let it run in the background when my machine is idle. And the software has to be compatible with the new ASIC boards coming out too. I guess which software do you recommend without much configuration besides putting in your btc address.

Comment: This question has already been adressed in many other answers. See:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x  and  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue BitMinter client is the easiest miner. You go to [bitminter.com](http://bitminter.com) and click the "start engine" button to start it. You may have to go by [java.com](http://java.com) and install Java if you don't have it already.

Once the window pops up click "devices" -> "probe all ports" in the pulldown menus to detect connected FPGAs and ASICs. Then click the "start engine" button to start mining.

There will be an update soon to support BFL (Butterfly Labs) ASICs.

If you want to mine on Avalon it has a builtin computer with mining software preinstalled.

*disclaimer: I am the author of BitMinter client.*