# How to mine your own Bitcoin fork?

Tags: miner-configuration, altcoin-development, genesis-block

I have my own Bitcoin fork. I have the src and I have the Linux, Mac and Windows clients. The Windows client is using Bitcoin Core for the wallet.

How do I go about mining the fork I created? I have servers at the ready and suspect I need to do something with the source probably...

I have an ASIC machine that I would like to mine it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mining software, just as if you were mining Bitcoin. Bitcoin Core does not contain mining code for mining on the main network unless you have changed that.

Those mining software usually have support for the `getblocktemplate` protocol, so you just point the mining software to Bitcoin Core's RPC interface and tell it to use `getblocktemplate`. How you actually do this depends on the mining software you choose and the software should provide instructions for doing this.

Comment: My goal is to have friends mine the coin externally. Am i right to think to run the daemon, example bitcoind and then use mining software to connect to the IP and port the server running the daemon?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score -1):

`. /abcoind setgenerate true`
 will work

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because it is wrong given that the asker states that they forked directly from the Bitcoin Core project, where the mining code has been removed.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/how-to-activate-the-mining-process-in-the-standard-bitcoin-client  so what is it then?

Comment: That answer is outdated, setgenerate was removed in 0.13.0. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/51170/5406