# How do I mine for coins?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-software

Finally synchronized the blockchain, yet not sure if I'm mining for coins. Where do I find out if I am or do I need something else?

Comment: Do you want to mine?

Comment: If you're wanting to mine, please understand that you're unlikely to mine *profitably* unless you have specialized hardware or a high-end graphics card. In the latter case, you'd not use the Bitcoin-Qt client itself for mining, but a separate program such as GUIminer. See also [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x?rq=1)

Comment: Graphics cards will not pay off any more unless you have free or very very cheap electricity.

Answer (score 0):

The bitcoin wallet is for receiving and sending bitcoins. When it is synced you are all set. You don't need anything else to receive and send coins.

Note that you can receive coins even if the wallet is not synced, you just won't see them before you are synced.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have downloaded Bitcoin-QT, the standard bitcoin client. This enables you to manage your addresses, to send and to receive Bitcoin.

If you want to mine bitcoin you will need special software, and if you want to mine bitcoin profitably you will also need special hardware. There is numerous questions about "how to mine with X" on this site, if you want to get started with that. See for example: [How can I start mining Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin)