# Please help, stuck at static 24Mhash/s?

Tags: mining-pools, hashpower, gpu-mining, miner-configuration

I'm fairly new to mining bitcoin, but I have read that using GPU can help improve performance. I currently am using GUIMiner (latest version) running on an OpenCL back-end but when I choose to use my graphics card I get less than I would without it. I also use Slush's pool, if that could have any relation?

PC Specs: Acer Aspire 5560 AMD a6-3420M APU with Radeon HD @ 1.50 GHZ 4GB Ram, is a laptop

Also can overclocking my pc improve performance?

Thank you,
          - bitcoin n00b

Comment: Please refer to [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x), if it doesn't deter you, this might also be of interest [How can I start mining Bitcoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1433/5406). Lastly, the short answer is, if you don't have an **[tag:ASIC]** these days, you will probably be converting energy cost to Bitcoin at a significant loss.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Using a graphics card to mine is completely fruitless, at this point you would not make a more than about 9 cents a month. Mining is now done on efficient, dedicated hardware that is designed just for this particular work. Mining on a laptop will absolutely kill it as they're not designed for continuous loads.