# Is it important to buy Bitcion hardware to start mining?

Tags: mining-hardware

I have just learnt about Bitcoin and Bitcoin mining. Is it really important to buy Bitcoin mining hardware like BFGMiner to earn Bitcoins ? Can't we just download the software and join a pool?

Comment: You should search for existing answers to questions before posting.  Your question is answered here:
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin/22916#22916

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Your existing hardware is general purpose and is so inefficient at mining Bitcoins that the value of the Bitcoins you mined would be a tiny fraction of the cost of the electricity it would use. Think of existing miners as aircraft carriers and your computer as a bow and arrow, at least when it comes to mining Bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what David said. However, if you have a GPU, then you can mine Scrypt coins like Litecoin or Dogecoin. For Nvidia GPUs, check out [CudaMiner](https://github.com/cbuchner1/CudaMiner), and for AMD GPUs, check out [sgminer](https://github.com/veox/sgminer). CPUs aren't really worth the effort to mine with, even for CPU-only coins like Primecoin (where an Intel Xeon can probably get you $1 a day).