# BITCOIN tutorials

Tags: miner-configuration

I am new to bitcoin. I know a little about bitcoin mining. 
Is there any tutorial or anything that i can read so that i can start bitcoin mining ?
Maybe a step by step guide or anything ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Please first check if a question has already been asked before you ask a new one. :)

Comment: Actually there is not question that explains about bitcoin and mining from start to a newbie! Hence i posted the question. If there is already a question , please do share the link for the same !

Comment: Actually, [nmat](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/1457/5406) explains what you have to do on the question I linked, and [hafnero](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22916/5406) updates for today's situation. There are no complete tutorials here, because ASICs usually work out of the box, and GPUs or CPUs don't cut it anymore. Today, it doesn't make sense for the average new user to start mining anymore: Bitcoin mining is not profitable unless you have very cheap electricity and very expensive hardware.