# External GPU for mining

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-setup

Of course, there are lots of ASICs out there with exponentially more hashing power. But I'm not yet ready to invest and dedicate to one coin. Is there a mining solution in which one can set up an external GPU enclosure and use those to mine? If so, how would one go about setting it up? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be overly broad because it's asking for a hardware recommendation, which will go out of date incredibly quickly.

Comment: Agreed, this is too broad and has essentially been asked before. This is basically asking how to start mining, and this question has been answered here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin

Answer (score 0):

You would likely spend as much buying a couple of decent GPUs as you would buying a small mining rig for sha256/scrypt (i.e. Bitcoin/Litecoin).

You can use "riser cables" to connect a PCI-E GPU to your computer's motherboard without it being inside the case but there is a limit on how long these can be (safety / fire risk).. I think 12-15" is about as long as they get realistically.

FYI:  GPU mining doesn't need a powerful computer, any old computer will do so long as it has suitable PCI-E ports and a few Gb of RAM.