# What program do I need to mining coins?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-software

I see there are hundreds of coins in the market. Can I use one program to mine all of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I start mining Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know that mining with personal computer isn't profitable.

**On-topic**:
There are a variety of algorithms, first you need to find out which algorithm the cryptocurrency you want to mine is based on.
Then find a CPU or GPU mining software that support that algorithm.

One CPU miner that is widely used, and support most of the available algorithms is [CPUminer-multi](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi) .

You can find the latest about mining on this forum https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=160.0