# How do I start mining bitcoins technically?

Tags: miner-configuration

I've read a lot of comments/posts on the internet and most of which are talking about buying a professional mining-machine.

However, I am just wondering, on the software side, how do I technically start mining?

For instance, is there any SDK I need to download? To what server address should I submit my hashing-computing results?

I would like to know some details in the technical level.

Thanks,

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1433/5406

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am just wondering, on the software side, how do I technically start mining?

I suspect that depends too much on the specific hardware etc to be answerable in detail on this website.

The hardware manufacturer often provides user guides that explain how to set up and run the miner.

For example, a search SOMETHING LIKE `Antminer S19 guide` will lead you to : https://support.bitmain.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403022268697-How-to-set-up-a-new-S19-S19-Pro

> 2. Setting Up the Server
> 3. Configuring the Server
> 4. Monitoring Your server
> 5. Administering Your Server

The same search will also lead you to Youtube videos that take you through the process including configuring pool settings etc.

You can similarly find online guides that describe the process in general. For example https://braiins.com/blog/how-to-mine-bitcoin-beginners-guide