# How do I set up my S9 and full node for solo mining?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, miner-configuration, asic, solo-mining

I keep seeming to get round about answers about this. I want to begin mining to my local general-use machine which acts as a node as it hosts the blockchain (aka.BTC-core). I HAVE an ASIC S9. I need a bit of a walk-through generating the blocks and having my machine take cracks at them locally without a pool. Inspired by some of the low hashes of found blocks recently, I think my s9 has a chance with a gigabit+ connection.

Comment: https://www.asicminervalue.com/miners/bitmain/antminer-s9-13-5th

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solo Mine with an AntMiner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36845/solo-mine-with-an-antminer)

Comment: I think I meant this related question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/110992/5406