# How to solo mine to my bitcore node

Tags: miner-configuration, solo-mining, asicminer

Currently running a full bitcore node (v23.0.0) on Ubuntu. Chain has fully downloaded and is taking to peers.
How do I point my asic (on the same network) to solo mine to my node?
I've found a how to on the. Conf for win but not ubuntu and nothing seems to happen when I try to open/ edit config thru the bitcore gui

Comment: By "bitcore" you mean "https://bitcore.io/" - right?

Comment: If you on the other hand mean Bitcoin Core, one of these two topics might already answer your question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/110990/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36845/5406. It may be helpful if you include the make of the ASIC you are trying to get online. (Asicminer is (was?) a specific manufacturer, so you might have meant a different tag.)